# OpenCv: How to save Mat::Rect into file?

Tags: c++, opencv, tracking

I capture camera image into image. I select the object from image and i track the object. But I want to save the selection into file because I dont want select the object every time.
This is my selection part;

```
Mat image;
Rect selection;

selection.x = MIN(x, origin.x);
selection.y = MIN(y, origin.y);
selection.width = abs(x - origin.x);
selection.height = abs(y - origin.y);
selection &= Rect(0, 0, image.cols, image.rows);
```

How can I save selection or How can I select the object for the first time?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't store a `Rect` directly using `FileStorage`, but you can store the integer values of `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`.

Write to File:

```
Rect rect;
// ... init your Rect

FileStorage fs("rect.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
if( fs.isOpened() ){
    fs << "x" << rect.x << "y" << rect.y;
    fs << "width" << rect.width << "height" << rect.height;
    fs.release();
}
else cout << "Error: can not save the rect\n";
```

Read from File

```
Rect rect;

FileStorage fs("rect.yml", FileStorage::READ);
if( fs.isOpened() ){
    fs["x"] >> rect.x;
    fs["y"] >> rect.y;
    fs["width"] >> rect.width;
    fs["height"] >> rect.height;
}
else cout << "Error: can not load the rect\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try [OpenCV file storage](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html?highlight=file%20storage#FileStorage) to save the rectangle it self. Or if You want to save the selected part of picture, then use [cv::Mat roi constructor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat) and then save using [cv::imwrite](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite).

Comment: As @warci stated, you can not save a rectangle itself (at least with release 2.4.6.1)